# How to make sure the wireless network is the network whose status is used for the top bar

Tags: wifi, networking

I have a successful wifi connection, yet the top bar is showing a network icon with an x on it (presumably indicating a bad network connection). I assume the cause is the two virtualbox networks I have. Is there maybe a way I can simply reorder things so the wireless network is first?

[image]

I'm thinking the ideal setup would be that these devices are not displayed at all by the Network Manager applet since they are unmanaged by Network Manager:

```
DEVICE    TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
wlp4s0    wifi      connected  AndroidAP  
vboxnet0  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
vboxnet1  ethernet  unmanaged  --         
lo        loopback  unmanaged  --
```

`lo` is not listed, so why are the VirtualBox networks listed?